# ob-tangle or not?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

I'm experimenting with [Uncle Dave's config](https://github.com/daedreth/UncleDavesEmacs) which is using a minimum init.el to launch `config.org`, which is full of elisp babel source blocks. Here's his relevant launching code:

```
(when (file-readable-p "~/.emacs.d/config.org")
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/config.org")))
```

However, I've seen this:

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ob-tangle)
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/myemacs.org"))
```

which seems to want `(require 'ob-tangle)` (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430029/whats-the-best-way-to-package-my-emacs-installation-packages-and-config-so-tha/25430745#25430745)). The Uncle Dave setup is working fine. I guess I don't know how it's tangling (which means running all the code blocks in the org file, right?) without somehow being told to. But then what is `org-babel-tangle-file` doing other than running all the code blocks in a file? And then there's the `:tangle yes` parameter on an individual code block. I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what Nick Dokos (who has helped me often) over at the org-mode mail list says:

> ...tangling does not run code blocks: it just writes them out to (one
>   or many) different file(s).  `org-babel-load-file` calls
>   `org-babel-tangle` which is an autoloaded function, so when it is
>   called, emacs arranges to load the file that defines it (i.e.
>   ob-tange.el[c]). So you don't need to to `(require 'ob-tangle)`
>   separately.

However, I don't know all the ins and outs of tangling in org-mode yet. But I would guess attaching `:tangle no` to a block would keep it out of the tangle file.

This is what I had been doing -- at least for small bunches of code:

```
#+name: setup
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :session ch1
(require math)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: setup

# Local Variables:
# eval: (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "setup") (org-babel-execute-src-block))
# End:
```

i.e., I'm using Emacs' [local file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) capability to have a Racket module loaded, and, as a bonus, start up a REPL session.

Another angle is to use org-mode's *Library of Babel* capability.

Comment: Cool trick =) Would you mind expanding on why you have your setup this particular way? I feel I'm missing something that could be useful here.

Comment: The particular file this `#+name: setup` and the local file variable is in requires Racket's math module. It wouldn't make any sense to have it start as part of Emacs' general initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The way I configured my init.el as a init.org is similar to the one you are quoting from Uncle Dave. I am not using `ob-tangle` for parsing all the src blocks to another file using `:tangle` as a argument. I just bind `org-babel-load-file` to a key so as to reload it whenI make changes.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i")
(lambda() (interactive)(org-babel-load-file "~/.emacs.d/init.org")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will implement. But what is the difference between `org-babel-load-file` and tangle stuff?

Comment: I tried to call from the init.org file but it end up with a recursive call. I am therefore not sure how the tangle method works, since in the example that I find online there is no `:tangle` in the src header. normaly tangling will mean creating the one .el file from all the src blocks in te org file, which is what happens anyway when you call `org-babel-load-file`

Comment: I think I'll ask over at the org-mode mailing list.

Comment: please post your findings here @147pm, The documentation is very minimal..

Comment: Yeah, this whole "minimal" org-mode docs then people asking tons of questions that don't really get categorized or summarized into an O'Reilly-style book is a real treadmill. But then Emacs is vast. Alas.